ICMPv6 solicitation request in PHP
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, 58);
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array('sec' => 1, 'usec' => 0));
$type = chr(135);
$code = chr(0);
$check = chr(0);
$check .= chr(0);

$reserverd = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(0);
$distMul = "ff02::1:ff26:13dc"; //solicitation node multicast address
$target = "fe80::3b40:f032:5726:13dc";
$id = inet_pton($target);
socket_set_option($socket, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_MULTICAST_HOPS, 255);
$package = $type . $code . $check . $reserverd . $id;
socket_connect($socket, $distMul, 0);
socket_send($socket, $package, strlen($package), 0);
$str = socket_read($socket, 2048);
socket_close($socket);

Above is a script to send ICMPv6 solicitation request.
here is Wireshark capture.

the problem is , the request never get any reply, according to the IPV6 doc, the script should get a "Neighbor Advertisement (Type 136)" reply, but this is not happening.

Are there any other devices on your network with IPv6-configured network interfaces?

@President James K. Polk,  This is on my home network. the IPV6 address shown above is my WIFI card. what you mean by "IPv6-configured network interfaces"? I am new to IPV6 networking. by the way, My Windows Machine installed IPV6 Tcp/Ip protocol
